# python GTK+ action in many files

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk, gtk3

I spread my code in several files but I do not know how to make the child file interact with the main file.

example fichier1:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# coding: utf-8

import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk
from TestMenu import Menu

class MainWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self)

        self.grid = Gtk.Grid()
        self.add(self.grid)

        self.label = Gtk.Label("An example of a Label widget.")

        self.menuBar = Menu()

        self.grid.attach(self.menuBar, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.grid.attach(self.label, 1, 0, 1, 1)

    def onClick(self, button):
        self.label.set_label('Test OK')

win = MainWindow()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Fichier2:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

class Menu(Gtk.Grid):

menuUi= "/home/vianney/programmes/Menu.ui"

def __init__(self):
    Gtk.Grid.__init__(self)

    action_group = Gtk.ActionGroup("my_actions")

    self.AddActionMenu(action_group)

    uimanager = self.create_ui_manager()
    uimanager.insert_action_group(action_group)

    menubar = uimanager.get_widget("/MenuBar")

    self.attach(menubar, 0, 0, 1, 1)

def AddActionMenu(self, action_group):
    action_group.add_actions([
        ("ActionMenu", None, "Edition"),
        ("AddGame", None, "Add Game", None, None, self.AddGame)
    ])

def AddGame(self, widget):
    self.label.set_label('Test OK')

def create_ui_manager(self):
    uimanager = Gtk.UIManager()
    uimanager.add_ui_from_file(self.menuUi)
    return uimanager
```

here is the menu file:

```
<ui>
    <menubar name='MenuBar'>
        <menu action='ActionMenu'>
            <menuitem action='AddGame' />
        </menu>
    </menubar>
</ui>
```

in this example I would have changed the contents of the label in the file 1 belong to the file 2 menu

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: I add the menu file

cordially

Comment: `GtkUIManager` has been deprecated for ages. Use `GtkBuilder` instead.

Comment: Et améliore ton anglais parce que c'est difficile de comprendre ce que tu essaies de faire...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve your goals but following the common Gtk way, would be to create signals to your own custom composite widgets.

Let's create a signal, called `add-game-clicked`, so when a user clicks that menu option a signal in the Menu class will be triggered / emitted.

To do that on your code, we add:

```
self.menu.connect ("add-game-clicked", self.onAddGameClicked)
```

And then, rename the method **`onClick`** to something more meaningful like **`onAddGameClicked`**

So, your main python file, let's call it **`main.py`**, will be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# coding: utf-8

import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk
from TestMenu import Menu

class MainWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self)

        self.grid = Gtk.Grid()
        self.add(self.grid)

        self.label = Gtk.Label("An example of a Label widget.")

        self.menuBar = Menu()
        self.menuBar.connect ("add-game-clicked", self.onAddGameClicked)

        self.grid.attach(self.menuBar, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.grid.attach(self.label, 1, 0, 1, 1)

    def onAddGameClicked(self, widget):
        self.label.set_label('Test OK')

win = MainWindow()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Then we need to create a signal on your custom composite widget. To do that we add:

```
__gsignals__ = {
    'add-game-clicked': (GObject.SIGNAL_RUN_FIRST, None, ())
}
```

below the class definition and then emit the signal when the right event happens:

```
def AddGame(self, widget):
    self.emit("add-game-clicked")
```

Its important to say that python is: indentation, indentation, indentation, and your **`TestMenu.py`** file it's not correctly indented.

So your **`TestMenu.py`** file should be like this:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import GObject, Gtk

class Menu(Gtk.Grid):

    __gsignals__ = {
        'add-game-clicked': (GObject.SIGNAL_RUN_FIRST, None, ())
    }

    menuUi= "Menu.ui"

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Grid.__init__(self)

        action_group = Gtk.ActionGroup("my_actions")

        self.AddActionMenu(action_group)

        uimanager = self.create_ui_manager()
        uimanager.insert_action_group(action_group)

        menubar = uimanager.get_widget("/MenuBar")

        self.attach(menubar, 0, 0, 1, 1)

    def AddActionMenu(self, action_group):
        action_group.add_actions([
            ("ActionMenu", None, "Edition"),
            ("AddGame", None, "Add Game", None, None, self.AddGame)
        ])

    def AddGame(self, widget):
        self.emit("add-game-clicked")

    def create_ui_manager(self):
        uimanager = Gtk.UIManager()
        uimanager.add_ui_from_file(self.menuUi)
        return uimanager
```

Also notice that setting full path to files in this context ain't good. Use relative paths in your project otherwise things become too rigid and less portable.

Using the supplied **`Menu.ui`** file we should get something like this:

[image: result]

After clicking the Add Game menu option, the label will change.